# Django ORM: All items not in table

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've got two models:

```
class SchedulerEvent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class SchedulerEventReceipt(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(SchedulerEvent, unique=True)
    generated_on = models.DateTimeField()
    paid_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of all SchedulerEvents that aren't in the SchedulerEventReceipt table for a particular user.  I kinda thought you'd be able to do something like this:

```
inner_qs = SchedulerEvent.objects.filter(user_id='1')
SchedulerEventReceipt.objects.filter(event__user_id='1').exclude(event__in=inner_qs)
```

But that doesn't work.  I'm a bit ashamed to admit that I don't know SQL well enough to figure out how to do this with `.raw()`.

The goal is to find all SchedulerEvents for a particular user that don't currently have an entry in the SchedulerEventReceipt table.

Comment: What you are doing is, filter all events with user_id `1` and exclude everything which has events with `user_id` = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering all events with `user_id=1` and exclude everything which has events with `user_id = 1` which results in an empty queryset.

Try this:

```
qs = SchedulerEvent.objects.filter(user_id=<user_id>).exclude(schedulereventreceipt__event__user_id=<user_id>)
```

which excludes all the corresponding `SchedulerEventReceipt` which has the current user as the `user_id`

Comment: Brilliant.  That seems to work.  Clearly my thinking on this was all cloudy.